# jQuery .click() function how to distinguish table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to use the .click function on the UP and DN so that when I press up, the .over class is moved over onto the upper row and when I press DN the .over class is moved over onto the lower row. My problem is that I dont know how to specify a for loop into the click function and be able to call each row. All I know is how to specify which action the click functions with div ids.

```html
<html>
 <style>
  .highlight{
   background-color: pink;
  }
  
  }
  .odd{
   background-color: lightgrey;
  }
  .even{
   background-color: gray;
  }
  .over{
   background-color: red;
 </style>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.c').addClass('highlight');
   $('.a').addClass('odd');
   $('.b').addClass('even');
 });
   
  </script>
  
 </head>
 <body>
<h2>2: Zebra Striping Demo</h2>
<table id = "myTable" width="200" border="1">
  <caption><a id = "up" href="#">UP</a> Zebra Striping Demo <a id = "down" href="#">DN</a></caption>
  <tr class = "a"><td>January</td> <td>February</td><td>March</td></tr>
  <tr class = "b"><td>April</td><td>May</td><td>June</td></tr>
  <tr class = "c"><td>July</td><td>August</td><td>September</td></tr>
  <tr class = "a"><td>October</td><td>November</td><td>December</td></tr>
  <tr class = "b"><td>Monday</td><td>Tuesday</td><td>Wednesday</td></tr>
  <tr class = "a"><td>Thursday</td><td>Friday</td><td>Saturday</td></tr>
  <tr class = "b"><td>Spring</td><td>Summer</td><td>Fall</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/90xxguma/

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .highlight{
                background-color: pink;
            }
            .odd{
                background-color: lightgrey;
            }
            .even{
                background-color: gray;
            }
            .over{
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){   
            $('.c').addClass('highlight');
            $('.a').addClass('odd');
            $('.b').addClass('even');
        var currentRow = -1;
        var totalRows = $('#myTable tr').length;
        $('#down').click(function(){
          if(currentRow != (totalRows-1))
            {
              currentRow++;
              $('#myTable tr').removeClass('over');
                            $('#myTable tr:eq('+currentRow+')').addClass('over');

            }
        })

        $('#up').click(function(){
          if(currentRow > 0)
            {
              currentRow--;
              $('#myTable tr').removeClass('over');
                            $('#myTable tr:eq('+currentRow+')').addClass('over');

            }
        })

    });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
<h2>2: Zebra Striping Demo</h2>
<table id = "myTable" width="200" border="1">
  <caption><a id = "up" href="#">UP</a> Zebra Striping Demo <a id = "down" href="#">DN</a></caption>
  <tr class = "a"><td>January</td> <td>February</td><td>March</td></tr>
  <tr class = "b"><td>April</td><td>May</td><td>June</td></tr>
  <tr class = "c"><td>July</td><td>August</td><td>September</td></tr>
  <tr class = "a"><td>October</td><td>November</td><td>December</td></tr>
  <tr class = "b"><td>Monday</td><td>Tuesday</td><td>Wednesday</td></tr>
  <tr class = "a"><td>Thursday</td><td>Friday</td><td>Saturday</td></tr>
  <tr class = "b"><td>Spring</td><td>Summer</td><td>Fall</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not the appropriate solution for this: use CSS.

[Alternating table rows](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html):

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

For the mouse click, use the [css `:active`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/) (and possibly [`:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Avisited)) pseudo selectors.

Comment: In addition to `:active`, I would also use `:visited` css pseudo selector to make sure the property does not disappear on release.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#up").on("click",function() {              
    $(".highlight").next().addClass("highlight").prev().removeClass("highlight");
})
```

---

```
$("#down").on("click",function() {                 
    $(".highlight").prev().addClass("highlight").next().removeClass("highlight");
})
```

try that

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
//use important for css .highlight class 

$('#myTable tr').on('click',function(){
  $('#myTable tr').removeClass("highlight");
  $(this).addClass("highlight");
});

//for mouse over and out
$('#myTable tr').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('over');
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('over');
});
```

[link example](http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/pg0ez04z)

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-* attrbiutes.You can assign the order of the rows to the data-order attribute and when you click up for example; you can check the order and you can assign the class to the row with the order-1 tr.

jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2vywq0m8/)

```
jsfiddle
```

let me know if it works for you